# filter select box options using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two selection boxes,one contains different country names and another contains all state names of all countries.

Then if i select `India` from country selection box, the state selection box has need to show all states of `India` alone and remove all other states from it.

I need to do this in JQuery, any one is there to guide me!!!!!

Comment: there are a lof of script, just need to google

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of states under array of countries, and `onchange` event append it to the states.

```
<script>


var states = [];

states['India'] = ["state 1", "state 1", "state 1"];



states['China'] = ["state 2", "state 2", "state 3"];


$(document).ready(function (){


    $('#country').change(
        function(){

            var temp = states[$(this).val()];

            $('#states').children().remove();

            for(var j=0; j<temp.length; j++){

                $('<option></option>').html(temp[j]).appendTo($('#states'));

            }

        }       
    )


})


</script>

<select id="country">
    <option id="India">India</option>
    <option id="Nepal">Nepal</option>       
    <option id="China">China</option>       
    <option id="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>             
    <option id="Russia">Russia</option>                     
</select>   

<select id="states">
    <option>null</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @karthi you should accept my answer by clicking on tick button at the left corner of top of my post if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

U better use different way

make two select box one is for country 
and another for state ( default disable)
when usee select country from first select box then get all state of that country via ajax in second select box..

that will be better way instead of upload all state together and then filter

Comment: possible [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999163/changing-options-in-select-box-based-on-different-select-options)