# Filter selectbox options depending on primary choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating some selectboxes where i need to restrict my options depending on the choice made in the primary.

Basically i have `Select field 1` and `Select field 2`.

Data for these selectboxes are parsed from a database.

Select field 1:

```
errortype_id | errortype_text
```

Select field 2:

```
errorreason_id | errortype_id | errorreason_text
```

Is there a straightforward way i can customsize the option data in `Select field 2` depending on the choice made in `Select field 1`? I have the variable/attribute in my `Select field 2` table to filter.

[image]

Comment: yes, you can "filter" the options

Comment: @Xander, could you perhaps guide me how this is done (jquery)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999163/changing-options-in-select-box-based-on-different-select-options). Basically, you need to add a change event and check `$(this).val()`. From there you simply create option-elements and add them as the html to your select box 2.

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var options = '';
    if($(this).val() == 'a') {
        options = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
        options = '<option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>';
    }

    $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

EDIT: I didn't understand if you wanted to actually filter the values, remove values, or add however many you wish. If you really want to filter out elements you can use my change event and combine that with [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Basically i think this is what i need. Forget all about filtering, in this context it doesnt matter i have realised. I can filter with PHP and use the `change` and `val` as you described to populate `select2` with the proper options from the choosen `select1`

Comment: An additional question. I have 3 select boxes which needs identical data and behaviour, how can i avoid replicating the javascript for those?

Comment: If, in the end, all you do is change the options of select2 based on the values, you could add multiple select boxes to the change-event. `$('#select1, #select3, #select4').change()...`

Comment: They should not all change with same value, but individually, with this i assume they get changed to the same.