# Django: Dependent modelchoicefield

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms, django-1.8

I have a bit of a problem.

I am pretty much new to django and I am having a problem in understanding on how I would make a modelchoicefield dependent to another modelchoicefield.

I have been searching for a while now and came across with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery).

Being a beginner, I tried the code as it is and fixed some very small issues but whenever I try to access the website (localhost) it downloads a text file that contains a single line of what appears to be a dictionary of some sort `{1 : asd}` and that's it, it doesn't display anything just downloads a text file.

I think it's because i have set the urls like this:

`url(r'^(?P<campus_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_schools, name='get_schools'),`

What I think I am missing is:

Setting the url right and
rendering or displaying of the fields

I would really appreciate a bit of help, advice, or even a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is the best way to do this.

[Filter selectbox options depending on primary choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318253/filter-selectbox-options-depending-on-primary-choice)

Very useful to know in future. I had a similar issue recently!

Edit: I'm so sorry, this is an old question and you replied to it to say you've resolved it. Good job!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a month old I tried studying javascript and turned out it was simple. Just filter and fill your dropdown through javascript like this

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
         <!--The parent dropdown-->
            $("#id_REGION").change(function() {
                var el = $(this);
                var select = document.getElementById("id_CITY");
                $("#id_CITY").val([]);
                select.length = 0;
                $("#id_CITY").append("<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">---------</option>");
            <!--Clears the field for new entry-->

                var reg = [{% for item in a %}"{{ item.Region_Designated_id }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];
                var city_name = [{% for item in a %}"{{ item.CITY }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

               <!--filling the dropdown-->
                for(var i = 0; i<reg.length; i++){

                <!--Filtering the entries-->
                    if(el.val() == reg[i]){
                        $("#id_CITY").append("<option id = "+ reg[i] +" value = \"" + city_name[i] + "\">" + city_name[i] + "</option>");
                    }

                }
            });
        });
```

This code uses two dropdowns making on dropdown dependent to another