# I have a select tag on a one pager and I want another select tag to appear when a certain option has been selected

Tags: php, html, forms, select, tags

the page is a form which will be sent to some email adresses when submitted. my problem right now is that I can't figure out how to make another select tag (dropdown) appear when a certain option is selected.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing options in select box based on different select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999163/changing-options-in-select-box-based-on-different-select-options)